# Making a `UIView` line go half rounded on center of itself

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitoolbar

I'm struggling with a problem:

I did create an `UIView` with subviews inside to make my own `UIToolBar`.
I added a `UIView` which acts like a delimiter line on top of it.

Then I decided to make one of the subviews rounded on center. But I need to find a way to "curve" the delimiter `UIView`.

Actually I have:

[image: my currents UIView]

I want:

[image: this one please]

Is there anyway to fullfill my goal programmaticaly in swift ?

I thought about importing an `UIImageView` and make the images according to the differents iPhone size but is there any other solution ?

Comment: you need to draw the outer view using bezier path !

Comment: You can add an UIImageView for the background of your UIToolBar, simplest solution I agree with you

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem by sandwiching a dark gray circle image behind the toolbar, and a light gray circle image in front of the toolbar but behind the button. It's a hack but it works perfectly if you match the colors, and it's easier than doing path drawing.